# What version of windows server 2008 do I have

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have been asked to help out with administering a windows server 2008 R2 server however, I'm trying to work out what version it has installed so I can work out if I need to upgrade it or not.

Is there a simple way to work out what version is installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a PowerShell prompt (console or ISE) and run:

```
(gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem).Name
```

(Other properties of `Win32_OperatingSystem` include all sorts of useful information.)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Start menu and right click **Computer** and select *Properties* from the context menu. From that window, see **Windows Edition** at the top.

If you don't actually have a reason to upgrade, you probably don't need to.